# Passar Imagens de uma tela para outra Android

Tags: imagem, android-activity, parse.com

Estou com um problema em um aplicativo que estou criando. Tem uma tela do aplicativo que pega dados do parse.com, no caso uma imagem, e queria passá-la pra outra tela, porém sem perder a qualidade. Eu até consegui passar a imagem pra outra tela, porém ela vem com uma qualidade muito ruin e borrada. Será que não tem outro jeito de receber a imagem, sem que ela perca qualidade?
Meu código é este

```
public class Eventos extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ListViewEventos adapter;
private List<GetEventos> eventos_lista = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eventos);
    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}

// RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Eventos.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Carregando Dados...");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Aguarde...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        eventos_lista = new ArrayList<GetEventos>();
        try {
            // Localizando a classe noticias no parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "Eventos");


            //colocando por ordem de data
            query.orderByAscending("Number");
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject titulo : ob) {
                // Localizando as imagens na coluna foto do parse
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) titulo.get("Foto");
                ParseFile img = (ParseFile) titulo.get("FotoEvento");

                GetEventos eventos = new GetEventos();
                eventos.setTitulo((String) titulo.get("Titulo"));
                eventos.setDescricao((String) titulo.get("Descricao"));
                eventos.setTextoEvento((String) titulo.get("TextoEvento"));
                eventos.setFoto(image.getUrl());
                eventos.setFotoEvento(img.getUrl()); //<<-Está é a imagem
                eventos_lista.add(eventos);
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewEventos);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewEventos(Eventos.this,
                eventos_lista);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

O adaptador do listview:

```
public class ListViewEventos extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
private List<GetEventos> eventos_lista = null;
private ArrayList<GetEventos> arraylist;

public ListViewEventos(Context context,
                       List<GetEventos> eventos_lista) {
    this.context = context;
    this.eventos_lista = eventos_lista;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<GetEventos>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(eventos_lista);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView titulo;
    TextView descricao;
    ImageView foto;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return eventos_lista.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return eventos_lista.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_eventos, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_eventos.xml
        holder.titulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TituloEvento);
        holder.descricao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.DescricaoEvento);
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_noticias.xml.xml
        holder.foto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImgEvento);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Set the results into TextViews
    holder.titulo.setText(eventos_lista.get(position).getTitulo());
    holder.descricao.setText(eventos_lista.get(position).getDescricao());
    // Set the results into ImageView
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(eventos_lista.get(position).getFoto(),
            holder.foto);
    // Listen for ListView Item Click
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, EventosAbrir.class);
            // Pass all data rank
            intent.putExtra("titulo",
                    (eventos_lista.get(position).getTitulo()));

            intent.putExtra("descricao",
                    (eventos_lista.get(position).getDescricao()));
            // Pass all data flag
            intent.putExtra("textoevento",
                    (eventos_lista.get(position).getTextoEvento()));


            intent.putExtra("fotoevento",
                    (eventos_lista.get(position).getFotoEvento()));
            // PEGA O ARRAY DE IMAGENS E ENVIA PARA A OUTRA TELA

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

A activity que recebe os dados, inclusive a imagem:

```
public class EventosAbrir extends ActionBarActivity {

String titulo;
String fotoevento;
String descricao;
String textoevento;
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eventos_abrir);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Get the result of rank
    titulo = i.getStringExtra("titulo");

    textoevento = i.getStringExtra("textoevento");
    // Get the result of country
    descricao = i.getStringExtra("descricao");

    //PEGA A FOTO QUE FOI PASSADA NA TELA ANTERIOR
    fotoevento = i.getStringExtra("fotoevento");


    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TituloAbrir);
    TextView desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DescricaoAbrir);
    TextView txtevento = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textoevento);

    ImageView imgflag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.abrir_foto);
    imgflag.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    // Set results to the TextViews
    title.setText(titulo);
    desc.setText(descricao);
    txtevento.setText(textoevento);

    // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
    // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
    //EXIBE A IMAGEM PASSADA NA TELA ANTERIOR
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(fotoevento, imgflag);
}
```

Observo que o getStringExtra pega a fotoevento como String, será que isso tem alguma influência?

**EDITADO**

Resolvido o problema. A classe ImageLoader carregava as imagens em 150x150 e as imagens que eu coloquei no parse.com são 512x512 e ao aumentar o tamanho da imageview ela perdia qualidade. Mudei os valores na classe ImageLoader e agora as imagens vêm com perfeita qualidade.